# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: The site is coming along really nicely, our community is dedicated and growing. There are some well written questions and answers here and I think we are well on our way to becoming _the_ official goto Blender resource for definitive answers.

Comment: is there a purpose in communicating with this bot?

Comment: @Vader I'm not sure what you are asking. This post is automated, but the *actions* it drives are for your benefit and Community Team looking on; a bit of self-reflection and a way to take stock in how you are progressing and where you can improve.

Comment: @Vader No, but it's ok to leave your thoughts here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Applying numeric input attribute changes on multiple objects at the same time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/applying-numeric-input-attribute-changes-on-multiple-objects-at-the-same-time)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to make a circular array using offset object as center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a way to have one material for cycles and the BI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/is-there-a-way-to-have-1-material-for-cycles-and-the-bi)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [unexpected reactions in a quiet simple rigidbody physics simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/unexpected-reactions-in-a-quiet-simple-rigidbody-physics-simulation)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Walk Mode in 2.69?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/walk-mode-in-2-69)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Blender Object keeps moving back to 0,0,0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/blender-object-keeps-moving-back-to-0-0-0)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I clear the render border?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/how-do-i-clear-the-render-border)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Use Python to add multiple colors to a NURBS curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6084/use-python-to-add-multiple-colors-to-a-nurbs-curve)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Exporting tiled texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/exporting-tiled-texture)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [custom color property in panel draw layout](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6154/custom-color-property-in-panel-draw-layout)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Comment: what does Net Score mean? which is best: high or low?